# What happens when a Sony SLT camera is operated with mirror up?

Tags: autofocus, sony, mirror, slt

What happens if you attempt to operate a Sony SLT (pellicle mirror) camera with the mirror up?  Does the camera detect this condition?  Will the camera shoot?  What happens to autofocus--can the camera fall back to contrast detection?  Is the increase in exposure value accounted for?

Comment: Are you sure that it can be operated with the mirror up? I thought the whole point of these cameras was that the mirror never moved. That said I don't own one and can't find the manual for one online to check.

Comment: The mirror must be moved manually, there is not motor to move it but it is movable by hand so that the sensor can be cleaned. It is a wonder why they did not simply produce a completely sealed unit which would prevent dust from reaching the sensor. I suspect the issue be with the sensor-shift stabilization system but that is just a guess.

Comment: Keep in mind that the focal-plane shutter is a mechanical part which may generate dust behind the mirror.  This is probably the reason the unit is not fully sealed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SLT-A55 at least no longer focuses but everything works, even with the mirror removed which you can do without too much difficulty. Exposure is off by about 1/3 EV.